# Array positions in wrong order after array_unique

Tags: php

in my code im using a array_unique to remove the duplicates in my array but when i do the variables in my array get the put in their original posiotions from the old array is there anyway do prevent this.

**Array $b:**

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => a [2] => b ) 

$SlideShowNames = array_unique($b);
```

**output:**

```
Array ( [0] => a [2] => b )
```

as you can see the b stays in postion 2 i would like it to be in position 1

Comment: Using `array_values`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$slideShowName = array_values(array_unique($b));
```

is what you're looking for